# Why PyCharm asking for "self" parametr in static function?

Tags: python, pycharm, open3d

I'm currently learning Open3D lib for python and got this problem. I tried to run this code:

```
import open3d as o3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cube = o3d.t.geometry.TriangleMesh.from_legacy(
    o3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_box())

# Create scene and add the cube mesh
scene = o3d.t.geometry.RaycastingScene()
scene.add_triangles(cube)

# Rays are 6D vectors with origin and ray direction.
# Here we use a helper function to create rays for a pinhole camera.
rays = scene.create_rays_pinhole(fov_deg=60,
                                 center=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
                                 eye=[-1, -1, -1],
                                 up=[0, 0, 1],
                                 width_px=320,
                                 height_px=240)

# Compute the ray intersections.
ans = scene.cast_rays(rays)

# Visualize the hit distance (depth)
plt.imshow(ans['t_hit'].numpy())
```

This code was taken from official [Open3D website](http://www.open3d.org/docs/0.15.1/python_api/open3d.t.geometry.RaycastingScene.html), but when I run it nothing happens. PyCharm says to me that "parameter `self` unfilled" [image]

On the open3d.t.geometry.TriangleMesh [doc page](http://www.open3d.org/docs/0.15.1/python_api/open3d.t.geometry.TriangleMesh.html) it's said that `from_legacy` is static function

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: maybe the method is overloaded. The signature of the method in the doc it's different from this

Comment: @Volzy, no, it's not overloaded

Comment: seems like pycharm is generating wrong stubs for pybind11 classes with static methods.

Comment: run it it should work it looks like a pycharm issue. (run it from terminal)

Comment: it is because the docs mention self, so pycharm thinks it is an instance method, since it cannot see the C++ code.

Comment: @SPGC modify the docs or the stubs i guess ... i don't know.

Comment: @Volzy I've just run it from terminal, nothing happened

Comment: @AhmedAEK I'm not sure it's good idea. Open3D is extremely big library, I'm not sure I can find it